# How to refactor this validation method

Tags: java, refactoring, code-duplication

I have a lot of duplicated code below. I am thinking if there is a way to clean it up and remove the lots of duplicated code. I think i should create a method which to do the logging and throw the exception? But i am unable to get my mind around on how to do it

```
  for (Shape shape : Shapes) {
        if (shape.getShapeName().isEmpty()) {
            final String mesg = String.format("Empty Shape.");
            log.error(mesg);
            throw new Exception(mesg);
        }

        invalidChar = p.matcher(shape.getShapeName()).find();

        if (invalidChar) {
            final String mesg = String.format("Invalid character(s) in Shape name %s",
                    shape.getShapeName());
            log.error(mesg);
            throw new Exception(mesg);
        }

        if (shape.getShapeDesc().isEmpty() || shape.getShapeDesc().trim().length() == 0) {
            final String mesg = String.format("Empty Shape description.");
            log.error(mesg);
            throw new Exception(mesg);
        }

        if (Character.isWhitespace(shape.getShapeDesc().charAt(0))) {
            final String mesg = String.format("Empty first character in Shape description %s", shape.getShapeDescription());
            log.error(mesg);
            throw new Exception(mesg);
        }

        p = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+");
        invalidChar = p.matcher(shape.getShapeDesc()).find();

        if (invalidChar) {
            final String mesg = String.format("Invalid character in Shape description %s", shape.getShapeDesc());
            log.error(mesg);
            throw new Exception(mesg);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can write a method which takes two parameters, a boolean and a string, and call the condition with the logging and the error throw in this method

```
void checkError(boolean condition, String message) {
    if(condition) {
        log.error(message);
        throw new Exception(message);
    }
}
```

and then instead of your conditions you can use

```
checkError(shape.getShapeName().isEmpty(), "Empty Shape.");
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @T.Garcin's answer,

This if statement:

```
shape.getShapeDesc().isEmpty() || shape.getShapeDesc().trim().length() == 0
```

Can be shortened to just the right condition, since it would be the same. But I'd suggest trimming the value in the Shape constructor then just calling isEmpty rather than having to remember to call trim everywhere.

That means you also don't have to do this check

```
if (Character.isWhitespace(shape.getShapeDesc().charAt(0))) {
        final String mesg = String.format("Empty first character in Shape description %s", shape.getShapeDescription());
        log.error(mesg);
        throw new Exception(mesg);
}
```